# Ocultar acción del action de un formulario html

Tags: html, html5

Hola quisiera saber si es posible ocultar la acción de mi formulario, pues está dando información del proceso que se ejecutará, lo cual podría ser un problema de seguridad.

```
<form name="cambiar_datos" action="index.php?action=modifdata" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

En mi caso si le dan **Ver Código Fuente de la Página** verán que el action invocará al archivo index.php con un action=modifdata.
Se puede proteger esa información?

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir más detalle? ¿A qué te refieres con que se está dando información del proceso que se ejecutará? ¿A qué problema de seguridad te refieres? Esto parece algo más que debas hacer desde el servidor que desde el lado del cliente, recuerda que la información que se mande a la parte del cliente no se puede ocultar o proteger de que sea vista.

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta. Por error no puse el código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En todo caso podrías hacer esto:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" .......>
```

con un input hidden pasandole un ID que solo vos sabrás que significa en realidad... (ej:)

```
<input type="hidden" value="tomate-queso-pimiento" name="action" id="action"/>
```

y en process.php tienes

```
if($_POST['action'] == '{tomate-queso-pimiento}') { .. hacer tal cosa .. }
elseif($_POST['action'] == '{jamon-cebolla-palmito}') { .. hacer otra cosa .. }
// y así sucesivamente)
elseif(!isset($_POST['action']) { echo "nos borraron el value del input hidden"; }
```

por lo que definis un nombre random para X accion, y en tu php, como es de lado servidor y nadie sabrá que hará en realidad, la mayor parte del tiempo ignorará, o probará manipularlo con las herramientas de desarrollador pero al final no logrará nada...

Comment: Potencialmente, podrías hacer el código dinámico y asociarlo a la sesión, de ese modo el token cambiaría cada vez que el usuario llegue al formulario, creando un nivel más de dificultad.

Comment: Lo de la sesión sería algo como if($_SESSION["logueado"] != "SI"){
  header("Location: index.php"); 
  exit(); 
} cuando un usuario se loguea correctamente asigna SI  a $_SESSION["logueado"]

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo con javascript, pero al final va a tener el mismo resultado. La URL de destino siempre se va a poder ver si se inspecciona. Resulta, que el HTML es un archivo público, así que, no tiene sentido ocultar esa información cuando va a seguir siendo pública por obligación. Y no creo que tengas problemas de seguridad si tomas las medidas adecuadas.